# Unable to update K8s manifest file by sed

Tags: sed, yaml

I have the below YAML file as like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    creationTimestamp: 2019-03-20T23:17:42Z
    name: default
    namespace: dev4
    resourceVersion: "80999"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dev4/serviceaccounts/default
    uid: 5c6e0d09-4b66-11e9-b4e3-0a779a87bb40
  secrets:
  - name: default-token-tl4dd
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"pod-labeler","namespace":"dev4"}}
    creationTimestamp: 2020-04-21T05:46:25Z
    name: pod-labeler
    namespace: dev4
    resourceVersion: "113455688"
    selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/dev4/serviceaccounts/pod-labeler
    uid: 702dadda-8393-11ea-abd9-0a768ca51346
  secrets:
  - name: pod-labeler-token-6vgp7
kind: List
metadata:
  resourceVersion: ""
  selfLink: ""
```

I am using sed to upate the file to be applied to a cluster, my sed command is like below:

```
sed -i \'/uid: \\|selfLink: \\|resourceVersion: \\|creationTimestamp: /d\' test1-serviceaccounts.yaml
```

However, I get the YAML file as like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    name: default
    namespace: dev4
  secrets:
  - name: default-token-tl4dd
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"pod-labeler","namespace":"dev4"}}
    name: pod-labeler
    namespace: dev4
  secrets:
  - name: pod-labeler-token-6vgp7
kind: List
metadata:
```

How should I modify my sed expression to get rid of the last line `metadata:`

Note: It should delete the last line.

I did try the below sed command however, it produces an error:

Updated sed command:

```
sed -i '/uid: \|selfLink: \|resourceVersion: \|creationTimestamp: /$ d' 128-res-test-black-dev4-serviceaccounts.yaml
```

Error from executing the above command:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 60: unknown command: `$'
```

The target file should look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
items:
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    name: default
    namespace: dev4
  secrets:
  - name: default-token-tl4dd
- apiVersion: v1
  kind: ServiceAccount
  metadata:
    annotations:
      kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
        {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"ServiceAccount","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"pod-labeler","namespace":"dev4"}}
    name: pod-labeler
    namespace: dev4
  secrets:
  - name: pod-labeler-token-6vgp7
kind: List
```

Comment: Looks at using a dedicated tool like yq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really try to use a dedicated yaml parser such as yq but if for what ever reason you cannot use such as tool, you can remove the last line with the following sed statement:

```
sed -rni '$!p' 28-res-test-black-dev4-serviceaccounts.yaml
```

Do not print the last line of the output (!p) and print everything else.

This can then be integrated with the existing sed command:

```
sed -i '/uid: \|selfLink: \|resourceVersion: \|creationTimestamp: /$ d' 128-res-test-black-dev4-serviceaccounts.yaml && sed -rni '$!p' 28-res-test-black-dev4-serviceaccounts.yaml
```